# "the package cache file is corrupted" error

Tags: updates

When I run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get multiple errors and warnings. The final error is:

```
The package cache file is corrupted
```

Here are the errors and warnings.

```
Reading package lists... Error!
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
E: Failed to fetch store:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_main_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_main_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_main_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_main_binary-all_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_main_i18n_Translation-en (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_restricted_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_restricted_binary-all_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_restricted_i18n_Translation-en (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_universe_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_universe_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_universe_binary-all_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_universe_i18n_Translation-en (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_multiverse_binary-all_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en (1)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: The package cache file is corrupted
```

***Question is different in that there are numerous warnings and errors. We have the same error message but not the same problem.***

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this fixes:

1. Open the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
2. Comment out either line `52` or `54` with a `#` at the start of your choice.
3. Now run `sudo apt update`

Now do (**WARNING**: copy and paste, don't leave out the `*`):

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt update
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not fix the problem

Comment: Updated answer please pay attention to the command `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`!

Comment: I could solve the problem without the first 3 steps. Just did rm -rf....

Comment: Calling out a line number might not be the most informative if the file has been modified.  Can you specify what content should be commented out?

Comment: Remove duplicate lines from that file. Comment out one of such duplicates.

Comment: removing list and updating did magic for me. Thanks